# turn off specific usb-port power when it is idle

Tags: drivers, usb, power-management

I am using Ubuntu 20.4.1,My laptop's internal wi-fi card's performance become week,so I am using a mini usb wi-fi dongle,and also some time I am using LAN connection.When I am using LAN,I want to close usb wifi dongle.for that I turned on "Airplae mode".It turns off the network data flow through usb wifi dongle.But, in spite of being idle ,usb dongle is getting hot.

So,is there any way I can turn off power to specific usb port.below is lsusb list,Device 006 is my target port

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b34f Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 248a:8514 Maxxter 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer thanks to Matt Symes of UbuntuForums.org. Get a list of your devices with:

```
for device in $(ls /sys/bus/usb/devices/*/product); do echo $device;cat $device;done
```

You should be able to cut power the specific USB port with

```
echo suspend | sudo tee /sys/bus/usb/devices/XXXX/power/level
```

where `XXXX` is the value `/sys/bus/usb/devices/XXXX/product` for your Wifi USB dongle listing.

To turn back on, replace `suspend` with `on`.